# How to replace a sequence of numbers separated by " _" in a string with a single number

Tags: perl

Say i have a string "mg_delay_1_2_it" , whereby i can have varying sequence of the numbers separated by "_" i.e i can have also a string like "mg_delay_1_2_10_it", or "mg_delay_1_2_5_25_30_it". I want to be able to replace the number section with a single number to produce several versions example: 
If the string is:mg_delay_1_2_5_25_30_it,
i want to be able to produce mg_delay_1_it ,mg_delay_2_it, mg_delay_5_it ,mg_delay_25_it and mg_delay_30_it from the original string. 
Please how do i do this efficiently in perl?

Comment: What answers do you expect? If you expect "In my opinoin ...", then the question is off-topic for being mostly opinionated. If you expect "do it like this `code`" then the question lacks any demonstration of own effort and is off-topic for being too broad. If you expect some basic perl tutorial, then it the question is off-topic for asking for tutorial. If you expect anythign else, then your question is off-topic for being unclear about what exactly your are asking. Try reading [tour] and [ask]. Then aim for a specific question on a programming problem you encountered while solving this.

Comment: I was expecting an asswer clearly....don't assume i haven't tried myself....my solution seemed too long and i actually wanted an efficient method like matching the string pattern and replacing using SED for example.

Comment: Well, why didn't you show your solution so as to give a reference for how efficient the answer needs to be? None of the downvotes is by me, but you probably would have received fewer if you had shown and then explained how much more efficient you need it and why. In case you encounter the need to improve your question scores some time in the future, this is a good candidate.

Comment: Ok noted. I am pretty new to this site...and quite honestly i dont care about down votes..no one should down vote anyone for asking questions regarding syntax. I will post what i tried in a bit. Problem solving is different from knowledge of syntax in a particular language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'mg_delay_1_2_5_25_30_it';
my $start = 'mg_delay';
my $end = 'it';
if (my ($res) = $str =~ /\Q$start\E_((?:\d+_)+)\Q$end\E/) {
    my @items = $res =~ /(\d+)/g;
    my @versions = map { $start . '_' . $_ . '_' . $end } @items;
    print Dumper(\@versions);
}
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'mg_delay_1_it',
          'mg_delay_2_it',
          'mg_delay_5_it',
          'mg_delay_25_it',
          'mg_delay_30_it'
        ];
```

Alternatively, if `$start` and `$end` are not known:

```
my $str = 'mg_delay_1_2_5_25_30_it';
if (my ($start, $res, $end ) = $str =~ /^((?:(?!_\d).)+)_((?:\d+_)+)(.+)$/) {
    my @items = $res =~ /(\d+)/g;
    my @versions = map { $start . '_' . $_ . '_' . $end } @items;
    print Dumper(\@versions);
}
```

Comment: haegland You are amazing! Thanks....that's an excellent method...I am learning a great deal from this site!

Comment: @heagland Actually problem with the solution you have is that "mg" can be any string and "it" can be any string as well. so i can have mgx_1_2_3_that as well.

Comment: @haegland....thanks for including the second alternate solution. Your method is quite advanced but compact. Thanks.